# Parse simple query construction using regex

Tags: sql, regex

I need to parse simple query construction
possible options

```
select col1,col2 

select col1,col2 where col1=1 and col2 = 'title'

select col1,col2 where col1=1 and col2 = 'title' order by col1

select col1,col2 order by col1
```

I have following regex

```
(select-?.*?)\s+(.*?){0,1}(?:\s+(where-?.*?)(.*)){0,1}\s(order by-?.*?){0,1}\s{0,1}
```

But it works strange in my case

[image]

I expected `order by` to be in Group 5, but in my case, it is a part of Group 4. I would like to have following order

- Group #1 - `select` word
- Group #2 - columns string
- Group #3 - `where` word - Is optional
- Group #4 - conditions string - Can be optional (if no where present)
- Group #5 - `order by` word - Is optional
- Group #6 - list of order by's - Is optional (if no order by present)

So, could someone point me, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Regex in picture is not what you have in code.

Comment: Is it a question to explain the pattern or asking for help to fix it?

Comment: A *regular expression* is vastly simpler than a *grammar for a language*. SQL is a language (like HTML!!) and cannot in general be *recognized* by a regular expression; rather it must be *parsed* by a grammar. A really simple **Recursive Descent Parser** should suffice for your task; and should be on every competent programmer's toolbelt.

Comment: By the way, `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here with group 4: `(.*)`

Greedy `.*` eats up the entire line. The regex has to backtrack to match `\s`, and the space before `col1` is the first space from the right, so it is matched. All the other groups are optional, so the regex is done.

---

Edit: OK, you want a regex, too...

This regex works on all the input given (may need adjustments):
`^(select-?[^\n]*?)(\s+[^\n]*?)?(?:\s+(where-?[^\s]*\s)([^\n]*?))?\s(?:(order\s*by-?\s)([^\n]*))?$`

Use it with `mg` modifiers.

It's loosely based off of your regex, but I can explain it if need be.

For convenience, here is the same regex with named groups (`mgx` modifiers needed): `^(?'select'select-?[^\n]*?)
(?'col'\s+[^\n]*?)?
(?:\s+(?'where'where-?[^\s]*\s)
      (?'cond'[^\n]*?))?\s
(?:(?'order'order\s*by-?\s)(?'by'[^\n]*))?$`

Comment: So, how it should be in my case ?

Comment: @IvanUrsul What regex flavor? JS?

Comment: @IvanUrsul I wrote a regex anyway